# Run .bat file from C#

Tags: c#, process, batch-file, io

i am facing a strange issue , i have a .bat file which contains a code for renaming a file , when i open the .bat file manually it does what it is written on it which is renaming a file , but when i try to open it programtically from C# , it doesnt do anything , it jsut open the file and do not compile what it is written into . i typed that code :

```
Process.Start(@"file.bat");
```

I also knew if you typed the path into cmd and pressed enter it will open the file and compile it , so i wrote that :

```
ProcessStartInfo psi3 = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + '"'+"D:\\my Work\\My Soft\\CA Delete\\CA Delete\\bin\\Debug\\file.bat"+'"');
Process p3 = Process.Start(psi3);
p3.WaitForExit()
```

But still the same issue : the file is being opened but never does what it is written into it.

EDIT : [I Figured why]

I took a snap shot of the CMD windows that should run the .bat file and i got ERROR :

```
ERROR : THE FILE SPECIFIED COULD NOT BE FOUND
```

but how ? when i run the .bat file manually it works FINE!!!

Comment: Try to set `WorkingDirectory` of `ProcessStartInfo`.

Comment: Why not read the batch file and process each line individually? As a managed alternative, .NET has the ability to do most file manipulation tasks; you may be able to use one of the many .NET scripting options available. Yet another alternative would be to embed Powershell which has the ability to be run from .NET.

Comment: Why not port the batch file contents to C# code? Renaming a file is simple using the `System.IO.File` class.

Comment: Kirill Polishchuk posted the answer.  If your bat file contains something like `rename file1.txt file2.txt` then cmd.exe looks in the current working directory for `file1.txt`.  So you need to set the `WorkingDirectory` property for your file to be be found.

Comment: @arx I dont understand what does WorkingDirectory mean

Comment: When you use a filename without a path (like `file1.txt`) how does Windows know where to find it?  The answer is that it looks in the current directory, also known as the working directory.  When you launch a process you need to tell Windows which directory to use for the current directory (in your case I guess it's the directory containing the batch file).  You do this by setting the WorkingDirectory property on your ProcessStartInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this.  [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)

```
psi3.RedirectStandardError= true;
psi3 .RedirectStandardOutput= true;
psi3.UseShellExecute= false;
```

Comment: I Edited the question , please check it

Answer (score 0):

You may be requiring additional admin previleges to execute what is intended in the Batch file. If so, use the alternative version of Process.Start():

```
Start(string fileName, string arguments, string userName, SecureString password, string domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the first line of the batch file this:

pushd %~dp1

This will set the batch files working directory.

martyn

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
String myBatchFileName = "name_of_file.bat";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myBatchFileName);
```

- Note that variable `myBatchFileName` is the actual name of .bat file.....