# Start process with default credentials

Tags: c#, process, io, environment, credentials

I am running a process using my credentials but , i wanted to use the default credentials , i mean using the current username and password , without going throuh the below code :

```
var pass = new SecureString();
pass.AppendChar('p');
pass.AppendChar('a');
pass.AppendChar('s');
pass.AppendChar('s');
pass.AppendChar('w');
pass.AppendChar('o');
pass.AppendChar('r');
pass.AppendChar('d');
Process.Start("file.txt", Environment.UserName, pass, "");
```

Because the application will work on different computers , so it should get the current credentials and use them.

EDIT

The problem is that the file i want to run is a .bat file that will do some cmd commands and it must be provided with a credentials to use

Comment: You impersonate the current user by default when you launch a Process...

Comment: Is this related to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322516/run-bat-file-from-c-sharp? Why duplicate then?

Comment: Sorry , it is just i had 2 separate questions

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand: if you want to execute a process using default credentials, simply don't pass anything:

```
Process.Start("file.txt");
```

If you need more complex syntax, redirect input/output, hide window or other things you can use [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).

**EDITED after user edit:**
You simply can't recover user password, it's not allowed.
As reported in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/36e1bcfa-a46a-47a8-8b21-78357efe866b):

> You can get the current identity of the user under which the current
>   thread is running (not necessarily the logged in user) using
>   `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.
>   Alternatively you can get the logged in
>   user name via the `Environment.UserName` property.
>   It is not guaranteed
>   to be the user running the current process however.
>   There is no
>   Windows API to get a user's password as passwords aren't stored in
>   Windows.
>   Instead Windows stores a one-way hashed version.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Process.Start(@"Path")`. By not providing any credentials, the current user's context is taken.

Comment: But the problem is the file i want to run is a .bat file that will do some cmd commands and it must be provided with a credentials to use

Comment: Which credentials have to be used in order to run the .bat file on your client's pc? Does it have to be a AD User?

Answer (score 0):

If there is inside the cmd someone re-asking you for the credentials,there is no way to have the password of the current user programmatically, so the only chanche you have is to ask for the user password again, but this would be probably a security hole.